# Find correspondence between 2 arrays of coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, coordinates

I have two large 2D arrays (3x100,000) corresponding to 3D coordinates and I would like to find index of each correspondence.

An example:

```
mat1 = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[10,11,12],[1,2,3]]).T

mat2 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]).T
```

So here I need to obtain indexes of 3 and 0. And I need to find each correspondence on around 100,000 coordinates. Is there a specific function in Python to do this work? Apply a for loop could be probl

```
res = [3,0]
```

To sum up, my need:

[image]

Comment: Sorry...I added a picture to be more accurate in my description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`Cython-powered kd-tree` for quick nearest-neighbor lookup](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query.html) -

```
In [77]: from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

In [78]: d,idx = cKDTree(mat2.T).query(mat1.T, k=1)

In [79]: idx[np.isclose(d,0)]
Out[79]: array([3, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks Divakar. It is very impressive. On my data, it last few seconds!